# iPhone - having a Ripple effect on a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, image-manipulation, ripple

I am attempting to create a ripple like effect on an imageView when it is touched down on, however I do not understand how to implement OpenGL for windows and porting it to iOS. I have attempted to use http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/dsaqua.aspx as well as cocos2d however I find the latter completely and utterly confusing. Would anyone be willing to give some suggestions or can point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hey!! Muller how you have done Ripple Effect. Could you please help me? I have tried below answer given by Jhaliya but not able to get ripple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below for ripple effect in iPhone

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition) 110 forView:view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

For more effects you can check this link :

http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIViewAnimationState

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this, there is a reason why this isn't a real enum but just an undocumented number!

Comment: @JustSid  : Agree with you because It's not in documentation currently so by the time it's available there is no harm to use the numberic value .

Comment: is there a way to have it do this effect in only in a certain area of the image? I am having it done with a tap gesture, however it applies it to the whole image.

Comment: Sorry but i m not able to get any animation effect using this code.. I have just replaced view with self.myImageView. Anymore changes required???

Comment: I use this code but cant get any animation....i just replace "view" with "imgView". help me if u have any idea for this

Answer (score 48):

If you want a ripple effect on a view you can use it.

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:2.0f];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect" ];
[myView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:NULL];
```

Comment: +1,animation working like charms...!,if u help me for ripple effect apply on user touch location is possible how do?

Comment: Is this code AppStore safe? Can I get rejected for using this?

Comment: i use this code it working...but i want to get animation on touch point on imageview...how can i do it ?

Comment: it's private, but undetectable by apple.. I wuold not ship with it

Comment: if you are using ARC, replace **UIViewAnimationcurveEaseInOut** with **[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]**

Comment: what makes something undetectable? what makes something private? Just curious before I use this - from an iOS Noob

Comment: @Vishal you can try this though It is old but it is working fine in iOS 8. https://github.com/fodormarton/SCWaveAnimation

Answer (score 6):

@Rony's CATransition Ripple in Swift

```
let animation = CATransition()
animation.delegate = self
animation.duration = 2
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
animation.type = "rippleEffect"
myView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

(This is my first post, so idk if I'm doing it right :D)

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
let animation = CATransition()
animation.delegate = self
animation.duration = 5.0
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name : kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
animation.type = "rippleEffect"
viewForAnimation.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried above mentioned codes but none work perfectly. Find out following source code.
https://github.com/willstepp/gl_image_ripple