# Ripple Effect on ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ripple

I want to create a ripple effect on a UIImageView from the point where user touches on the screen. what is the best and simple method for doinf this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973530/iphone-having-a-ripple-effect-on-a-uiimageview

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973530/iphone-having-a-ripple-effect-on-a-uiimageview).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];        
    CGPoint lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];   
    //animation code
}
```

Using above method you have set UIimageView center on lastPoint and play your animation code.
It will work that u want.