# "ripple effect" on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, animation

I am now trying to make Ripple Animation with code Below by this code i getting animation at same location every time

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:2.0f];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect" ];
[imgView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:NULL];
```

but i want to get animation on touch point on imageview 
mean animation will occur at that point where user will tap on UIImageView

Answer (score 3):

I think below code can help you.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition) 110 forView:view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can also better visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973530/iphone-having-a-ripple-effect-on-a-uiimageview) post which is similar to your post.

Comment: i apply this code but i cant get animation....i just replace "view" with "imgView".

Comment: Please also visit mentioned [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973530/iphone-having-a-ripple-effect-on-a-uiimageview)

Comment: i visite that link but i cant get animation.....how can i get animation from your code ?

Comment: See if this [link](http://maniacdev.com/2011/12/example-how-to-make-realistic-water-ripples-with-cocos2d-very-impressive/) can help you.