# How do I do a ripple effect on a UIButton under iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, core-animation

When I tap my `UIButton` I want there to be a ripple effect, essentially several circles emanating from it, growing and lowering their opacity at the same time.

My initial reaction is to have several `UIImageView`s of circles and `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` to a slightly larger size while lowering their `alpha` at the same time. But I feel like that isn't the best option as it seems like creating images just for it seems silly, and it may create some unnecessary overheard.

What's the best way to go about accomplishing this? Bonus points if you don't use private APIs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973530/iphone-having-a-ripple-effect-on-a-uiimageview

Comment: @PratyushaTerli That's a private API, no bonus points for you. :P

Comment: @Doug whatever the available solutions are, please don't ask the same questions twice

Comment: @DougSmith Are you a beginner? You think UIView animations are a private API? or you have some other definition for private API?

Comment: This is incorrectly marked as a duplicate. The other question refers to adding a ripple warping effect to a UIImageView, using OpenGL or similar. This question is asking how to add rings expanding from behind a button after it's tapped. Entirely different question and answer.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli He's referring to the "rippleEffect" animation type, which is indeed private and undocumented.

Comment: @DougSmith I too had a requirement to add ripple effect on views, circles emitting from view, I did that using CALayer.  I wrote a generic code to add rippleeffect to any view .You can find sample project here https://github.com/anoop4real/rippleEffect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create several Transparent `UIView`s added behind the button. Set them up like so (pseudo code):

```
UIView *ripple = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(initial frame)];
[ripple setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[ripple.layer setCornerRadius:ripple.bounds.size.height /2]; //Assuming square images
[ripple setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[ripple setBorderThickness:4]; //Or whatever thickness you want
```

This will create rings that are rendered at runtime (rather than images).
Then you can just animate their scale using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`.

I've used this approach on the animation of the Logo in my GroovePond app. (not a plug!) 
Just search for it in the app store to see what I mean, its free, and the animation i'm referring to is on the first launch screen. Obviously in your case you can also fade the opacity out too.

While you could look into more complex ripple effects that deform the views around them, simple flat rings rendered as above would be more in keeping with iOS7's flat design, although I guess it would depend on the style of your app.