# Add ripple effect to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ripple

I'm trying to add ripple effect to UIView using the code below.

```
let animation = CATransition() 
animation.delegate = self 
animation.duration = 2 
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut) 
animation.type = "rippleEffect" 
myView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: let animation = CATransition()
animation.delegate = self
animation.duration = 2
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
animation.type = "rippleEffect"
myView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)

Comment: There is no such `CATransitionType` as `rippleEffect` - you can't just set `type` property to whatever comes to your mind and expect it to work.

Comment: @mag_zbc He probably got them from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973530/iphone-having-a-ripple-effect-on-a-uiimageview) itself. On a side note, tried with `CATransitionType(rawValue: "rippleEffect")` no luck

Comment: Please share code/example/link.