# iOS Animation Success Popup

Tags: ios, animation

How to create animation like this or should I use a gif for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a gif is the most easy way to achieve this. For using Gif images you can use SwiftGif Origin Library [SwiftOriginGifGithubLink](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif)

and you can use your code like this sample code:

```
let imageGif = UIImage.gif(name: "imageGif")
```

Second option for this is using Lottie Animation. [LottieAnimationGifGitHub](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve those ripples to a `UIView` ([see this answer for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014996/2810196)) which can be added to the check mark image view which will be moved continuously around.

To be more specific:

A container view which contains two subviews. One will be the Rippling view and another would be the check mark image view. Move the container view diagonally to get the moving animation and add ripples to the Rippling view so that the ripples are produced continuously.

There can be many other ways but this one came to my mind first and seems to easy to implement. Other ways can be:

- Gif
- Lottie animation
- May be a different approach

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple way to achieve this, also it doesn't rely any third party library -

**Steps**

1. Create different images for different state of this image (eq. one with smaller outer circle, one with medium size and one with full outer circle)
2. Create an array of `UIImages` with all the images created in step 1 (images should be in sequence, ofcource)

eq.

```
func setAnimatedImages() {
        var images = [UIImage]()
        for name in ImagesNames {
            if let image = UIImage(named:name) {
                images.append(image)
            }
        }
        self.imageView?.animationImages = images //set this image array to UIImageView
    }
```

3. Start and stop animation -

Start animation

```
self.imageView?.startAnimating()
```

Stop animation

```
self.imageView?.stopAnimating()
```